# How to solve version error in angular cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am facing this "Angular version error", how can I solve this?[The above image shows the current version of ng cli and the error that I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rj36.png)

Comment: `@angular-devkit/build-angular` package is on v14, downgrade this package to v13, or upgrade everything else with `ng update`

Comment: The image is not helpful. It would be more helpful to copy the command output and paste it as text. This way the question is also accessible to users with visual disabilities. Additionally, the question can be found easier by other users with the same error.

Comment: "This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^14.0.0,     
but Angular version 13.3.11 was found instead."

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates

ncu -u

npm install
```